# Cannot read property 'refetch' of undefined

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

this my code

```
const NewVerificationCode = () => {
  const { loading, error, data = {}, refetch } = useQuery(CONFIRMATION_CODE, {
    skip: true,
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
  });

  return <div onClick={() => refetch()}>CONFIRMATION</div>;
};

const CONFIRMATION_CODE = gql`
  query {
    my {
      sendNewTokenForConfirmation
    }
  }
`;
```

when i make a request i get a error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'refetch' of undefined

Comment: `refetch` should be in the result `useQuery` so I don't know what is wrong here. But I think that using a mutation or `useLazyQuery` seems to be better suited for your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `data = {}`

looks like you tried to 'escape' from undefined `data` error - not recommended method ... use

```
if(loading) return <Loading />
```

... before main content or

```
if(data) return <div onClick={() => refetch()}>CONFIRMATION</div>;
return null;
```

`skip` option blocks hook from execution, so no `refetch` possible.
Simply use `useLazyQuery` or use some state to control `skip` option, sth like:

```
const [blocked, setBlocked] = useState(true);
const { loading, error, data = {}, refetch } = useQuery(CONFIRMATION_CODE, {
  skip: blocked,
  notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
  fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
});

if(data) return <div onClick={() => {if(blocked) setBlocked(false) else refetch()}}>CONFIRMATION ... {data.someValue}</div>;
return null;
};
```